# Waiting for file to be created

Tags: php, msbuild

I'm trying to compile an executable via PHP with msbuild which compiles my C# source, the majority of the script relies on the executable being created so it must wait for msbuild to compile the source.

If I don't put any sort of while loop it will compile fine and the executable is created but the problem is the rest of the script executes to fast and the end result isn't correct.

so at the moment I'm using this..

```
exec('C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Compile\Myprogram\Myprogram.sln /p:Configuration=Release');

while (!file_exists('C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Compile\Myprogram\bin\Release\Myprogram.exe')) sleep(1);
```

However in this scenario it's almost as if the exec command never gets ran at all. It gets stuck in an infinite loop and eventually times out resulting in the exe never being compiled.

Any suggestions on the proper way to go about this?

Comment: Are you sure the user running the web server has permission to run this command and that all the appropriate environment variables are being set up. PHP should block until the external program is complete  making your while loop unnecessary.

Comment: Yes I believe so, because if I remove the while loop the exec command runs fine and msbuild compiles the executable. The problem is the rest of the script runs aswell before this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it as follows:

```
$output = array();
$cmd = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Compile\Myprogram\Myprogram.sln /p:Configuration=Release  && exit';
exec($cmd, $output);
```

Comment: Well in a sense I don't want it to run in the background. It does need to hang until it ends. It's not hanging at the exec command though it's hanging at the while loop

Comment: Your command is probably failing right off the bad because of lack of permissions or not all required values being accessible in the environment of the user running web services. Not sure about it on windows but you can access std err by redirecting stderr to std out, try adding `2>&1` to the end of your command

Comment: @Orangepill could be, but there's another option: adding the ` && exit` at the end of the command will "help" the command exit after execution when it's running on IIS server, see comments in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php and `$output` can be used to print the result (debug)

Comment: @Orangepill directing error to stdout `2>&1` is good when you're working on Unix, not on Windows machine.

Comment: Perhaps using proc_open instead of exec would be more informative then , you will then be able to access  stderr

Comment: Thank you. While I'm still having an issue I can now echo the entire output of msbuild and see what's going on.

Comment: @user2379231 what did you find ?

Comment: It was a permission error after all. After running process monitor to see what was going wrong and where I noticed a access denied error at "Network service\Appdata" giving iusr permission to that location seemingly fixed the error.